# Obter div acima da atual

Tags: javascript, jquery

Possuo um conjunto com varias divs,

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

Estou dando each nelas, e preciso saber qual é o numero (html) da div acima, por exemplo se eu estiver na div 4 eu preciso saber o numero 3 que e da de cima..

Comment: Queres saber o index ou o HTML que está nessa div?

Answer (score 2):

Podes usar o `.prev()`.

Se quiseres o index:

```
.prev().index(); // começa em 0, talvez queiras ".prev().index() + 1;"
```

se quiseres o HTML:

```
.prev().html();
```

Exemplo:

```js
var div3 = $('div:eq(2)');
var div2 = div3.prev();

div3.html('eu sou a div 3 com index 2');
div2.html('eu sou a div anterior à 3 com index:' + div2.index());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

E ainda outro exemplo com funcionalidade parecida: http://jsfiddle.net/aqfq45hh/

Answer (score 1):

Isso ai:

```
.prev(); para ir para o elemento irmão anterior.

.next(); para ir para o elemento irmão seguinte.
```

para acessar o indice dele atual, utilize

```
.index();
```

No seu contexto atual ficará:

```
$('element').prev().index();
```